# Copy Excel Worksheets with Specific Name from Multiple Workbooks to New Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon,

The code below copies Excel worksheets named "CLS" from multiple Excel files into a new document and names it Financial Metrics for CM.xlsx. Unfortunately it doesn't copy any worksheets where "CLS" is part of the worksheet name (which I also need to be included).  I have attempted adding `DIM ws = worksheet` as part of wildcard when searching, but to no avail.  Should I try writing an 'If' string instead to yield my desired result? I'm at a loss.

```
Sub CopyWS()
    Dim wbOpen As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\Financial Monthly Report\"
    Dim strExtension As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error Resume Next
        ChDir strPath

        strExtension = Dir("*.xlsx")

        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
        wbNew.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Final\Financial Metrics for CLS", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal

            Do While strExtension <> ""
                Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)

                With wbOpen
                    .Sheets("CLS").Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
                    wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
                    .Close SaveChanges:=False
                End With

                strExtension = Dir
            Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can loop through each worksheet in the newly opened workbook and check that the name contains the string `CLS`.

```
   Do While strExtension <> ""

        Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)

        Dim checkSheet as Worksheet
        For each checkSheet in wbOpen.Worksheets
            If UCase$(checkSheet.Name) Like "*CLS*" Then
                checkSheet.Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
                wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Name = wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1)
            End If
        Next

        wbOpen.Close SaveChanges:=False

        strExtension = Dir

    Loop
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I received a 'Next without For' Compile error when inserting this code even though the 'For' is there.

Comment: @novice Scott was missing an End If